# In what order of qualifier, resource value be searched

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having dimens.xml file in

- values
- values-land
- values-sw600dp
- values-sw600dp-land
- values-w800dp

In what order values will be searched(suppose if values-sw600dp-land is selected for current device and value is not present in it then which next dir will be searched until the value is found)?

And if am holding 600*960 dp device in landscape mode which out of values-sw600dp-land and values-w800dp will be selected?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Comment: so for second question order will be: values-sw600dp-land -> values-sw600dp -> values-w800dp -> values-land -> values? and this will answer my first question too :)

Comment: That sounds about right.